# Is JAX-RS also part of JDK distribution?

Tags: jax-rs

Is JAX-RS part of jdk distribution like JAX-WS which comes insider Java 1.6 standard?

If yes, what jdk version is required to run?

Answer (score 1):

No... it is part of [Java EE](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/). To use it you need either

1. An implementation like [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/), so that you can use it in a plain servlet container like Tomcat.
2. Use a Java EE compliant server like Glassfish or Wildfly (JBoss), which already comes with an implementation.

If you want (need) to use Java 1.6, then if you want to go with option 1, use Jersey version 2.6 (If you're using Maven, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27894395/2587435)). If you want to go with option 2, then go with Glassfish 4.0 (not 4.1 or anything higher) or JBoss 7

If you can use any JDK version, then I would recommend using the latest versions of any of the above components.