# A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList and MIME media type application/json was not found

Tags: java, json, jersey, jax-rs, moxy

I am trying to get a web service to work which returns a JSON (JAX-RS with jersey implementation on Tomcat). However, I am getting the below exception. I have looked at the similar problems here, but none of the solutions work for me, and it's been more than half a day :(

```
07-Nov-2017 20:47:17.109 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List<org.saurabh.Message>, and MIME media type application/json was not found.
The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json ->
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General

07-Nov-2017 20:47:17.110 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.logException Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
 javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List<org.saurabh.Message>, and MIME media type application/json was not found.

    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:284)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:500)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List<org.saurabh.Message>, and MIME media type application/json was not found.

    ... 30 more
```

The resource class is as follows:

```
package org.saurabh;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Path("/messages")
public class MessageResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Message> getMessages() {
        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
        messages.add(new Message(1L, "Hello India", "Saurabh"));
        messages.add(new Message(2L, "Hello World", "Saurabh"));
        return messages;
    }
}
```

The model class is as follows. I have annotated it with @XmlRootElement annotation (as suggested in some other answers), and has a no-arg constructor.

```
package org.saurabh;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Message {

    private long   id;
    private String message;
    private String user;

    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(long id, String message, String user) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.saurabh</groupId>
    <artifactId>JAX-RS-Rest-Tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Example API</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.jersey</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Example API</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Note that if I change the return type to application/xml, then it works fine. Its just that for the JSON, it keeps on giving this error.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public List<Message> getMessages() {
    // works fine
}
```

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27935273/jersey-2-6-jackson-provider-registering

Comment: @Jerry06: The answer there is using Jackson, and then extending the configuration class. I thought that there must be way out of the box to handle this.

Comment: XmlRootElement should not be required. Last time I used it, it was with JAX-WS, for SOAP web services.

Comment: @LppEdd Removing XmlRootElement doesn't help either :(

Comment: Okay, got it. Since you're not using Jackson, you need to write a custom MessageBodyWriter for your types. See http://programmingitch.blogspot.it/2014/03/creating-simple-jax-rs-messagebodywriter.html

Comment: @LppEdd: What if I use Jackson? Then do I still need to write my own custom MessageBodyWriter? Can you please guide me on how to use Jackson instead of Moxy. Thanks !

Comment: @OneMoreError Take a look here https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/

Anyways, I strongly suggest scaling up to something more comprihensible like Spring (see @RestController).

Answer (score 1):

The MOXy dependency you're trying to use is for Jersey 2.x. You need the one for 1.x, since that's what you're using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.3</version>
</dependency>
```